# How to execute batch using custom button (Javascript code)

Tags: apex, batch, custom-button, javascript-remoting

Is there a way to execute apex batch using custom button (Javascript code) and show popup once the batch is done?

Comment: have you read http://sfdc.arrowpointe.com/2009/01/08/invoke-apex-from-a-custom-button-using-a-visualforce-page/ ? hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code contains the execute batch job in js.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/apex.js")} 

var apexClassArray= sforce.connection.query("SELECT Id FROM ApexClass WHERE Name ='ProcessProfitDataBatch'"); 

recordsclassid= apexClassArray.getArray("records"); 

var checkBatchRunningRecords= sforce.connection.query("SELECT ApexClassId, status FROM AsyncApexJob WHERE ApexClassId ='"+recordsclassid[0].Id+"' AND Status NOT IN ('Completed','Aborted','Failed')"); 

records= checkBatchRunningRecords.getArray("records"); 

if(records.length>0){ 
window.alert("The batch job is currently executing. Please wait for it to complete."); 
} 
else{ 
window.alert('The Integration batch job has started.'); 
var batchid=sforce.apex.execute("WebServiceExecuteBatches","ExecuteProfitProcessData",{}); 

}
```

Apex Class:

```
global with sharing class WebServiceExecuteBatches{
   WebService static string ExecuteProfitProcessData(){
    string q = 'soql query';
     ProcessProfitDataBatch b = new ProcessProfitDataBatch(q);
        ID batchprocessid=Database.executeBatch(b); 
        return batchprocessid;
        return null;
   }
}
```

Comment: Could you please also post "WebServiceExecuteBatches" class what's inside it?

Comment: added it in answer